# Sorting a collection by multiple fields

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I need to sort a collection. 
For example, I have

```
Austin 12/3/2012   
Sam 100 12/3/2012   
Sam 200 14/3/2012   
Bubly 300 12/3/2012   
Bubly 300 15/3/2012  
ram 100 13/3/2012
```

Now if the sort order is Name, datetime
then output should be

```
Austin 12/3/2012    
Bubly 12/3/2012   
Bubly 15/3/2012   
ram 13/3/2012    
sam 12/3/2012    
sam 14/3/2012
```

If he sort order is Datetime , Name then
it should be

```
12/3/2012 austin
12/3/2012 bubly
12/3/2012 sam
13/3/2012 ram
14/3/2012 sam
15/3/2012 bubly
```

Accordingly for other items. How do i do this ? How do I take the order of columns for sorting.

Comment: looks like you want to order it dynamically (depends on some parameters)?

Comment: `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` ?

Comment: You're not very clear here, how are you indicating what you want to order by?  Are you trying to pass in a delegate function to manage the ordering?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Linq function [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) after using [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to perform further sorting.

```
listOfRecords.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Date)
```

Comment: The problem here is the order of column is not defined ?? some times it can be name then date , sometimes it can be date then name.. so how do i write generic statement.

Comment: How the order of column is going to identified? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: @user1687824, you can use a "SortDimensions" list to achieve this. See my answer below, but you may need to use another type for the SortDimensions object other than `List<object>`.

Comment: If this is a problem then just write wrapper function where you can pass the sort order as parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
yourList.OrderBy(o => o.DateTime).ThenBy(o => o.Number);
```

Answer (score 4):

First you create two functions:

```
var SortByDate=(p=>p.Date);
var SortByName=(p=>p.Name);
```

Then you have, for example, a List containing the two

```
var SortDimensions=new List<object>({SortByDate,SortByName});
```

Then you if you want to sort by first date then name you do:

```
myList.OrderBy(SortDimensions[0]).ThenBy(SortDimensions[1]);
```

Now, here is the tricky part, if you want to sort by name first then date you just alter the order of the functions in the SortDimensionsList:

```
SortDimensions.Remove(SortByName);
SortDimensions.Insert(0,SortByName);
```

This way, the same OrderBy statement will give you a different result.

PS. Admittedly, this is rather close to being pseudocode since you may have to use something other than `List<object>` for the SortDimensions collection to avoid compiler errors, but I don't have access to an IDE at the moment, but the spirit of the answer remains the same. Create a collection, store delegate functions in it, then alter the order within the collection to achieve different sorting dimensions using the same generic code.

Comment: Isn't it better to just `Reverse` the order of elements in `SortDimensions` instead of `Remove` and re-`Insert`? This approach is nice.

Comment: Well, there may be three or four sort dimensions, and the OP may want to sort first by ABCD then by BACD. This approach is more flexible in my opinion.

Comment: if i take this aproach , will the collection be looped as many times as coulmns/fields i need to sort ?

Comment: Yes, but it will also be looped the same amount of times using the other approaches as well. The LINQ clause is the same as the other answers.

Comment: How/Where do i define the function var SortByDate=(p=>p.Date); ??

Comment: Where: Depends on your code. How: Just enter the first two lines of code in the example.

Comment: I get the idea , But i am still not able to get the code When i define the function var SortByDate=(p=>p.Date); , the var is not at all recognized , am i doing something wrong ??

Comment: OK, so let us say that you have a class called MyClass which has a Date member (for simplicity's sake it is a string) and a Name member (also a string). Try writing `Func<MyClass,string> SortByDate=(p=>p.Date);` and `Func<MyClass,string> SortByName=(p=>p.Name);` and `List<Func<MyClass,string>> SortDimensions=new List<Func<MyClass,string>>(){SortByDate,SortByName};` Does that compile?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, I wrote var's in the example because I wanted to illustrate the concept of using delegate functions. var can only be used when the compiler can deduce what class to use, and in this case it could not.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class to hold your information

```
public class NameDate
{
    private string name;
    private DateTime date;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }
}
```

I would then populate a `List<NameDate>` to hold your items. When this is done, to sort the items you can use LINQ

```
List<NameDate> someList = new List<NameDate>();
someList = GetNameDateList();
var orderedByNameList = someList.OrderBy(e => e.Name);
var orderedByDateTimeList = someList.OrderBy(e => e.Date);
```

I hope this helps.